# Programmatically export eclipse formatter profile XML into .prefs

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

My team uses code formatting conventions defined in an eclipse profile XML file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<profiles version="12">
<profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="This Team's Formatting Convention"  version="12">
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_ellipsis" value="insert"/>
...
```

I am using eclipse as a command-line formatter, using a command like the following:

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter \
    -config ${JAVA_FORMATTER_CONFIG_FILE} ${*}
```

This only works when `${JAVA_FORMATTER_CONFIG_FILE}` is an eclipse preferences file with a filename like `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` and contents:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

How do I programmatically obtain the `.prefs` file without manually importing the XML profile from the eclipse UI?

Comment: The XML file can be easily converted to a properties file using XSLT, regular expressions or reading the ID/value pairs from XML and saving it to a properties file: `<setting id="${id}" value="${value}"/>` => `${id}=${value}`. Or did I misunderstand your question and it's not about converting the formatter profile XML to the `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`?

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure if there was any special handling or mapping of the XML to .pref values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Eclipse Oxygen workbench,

- Export current preferences: ***File -> Export -> Preferences***
- Select "Java Code Style Preferences"
- Choose a name and a destination and save (seems the .epf extension must be used)

The file will contain (among other things) the custom fomatter configuration

```
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/formatter_profile=_my-java-formatter
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/formatter_settings_version=13
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.formatterprofiles=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8" standalone\="no"?>\n<profiles version\="13">\n<profile kind\="CodeFormatterProfile" name\="my-java-formatter" version\="13">\n...
...
```

Then you can run the Formatter as

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -config eclipse-formatter.epf Test.java
```

Output:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/luis/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.8.3.20180227-2137.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://496.fwk1538849250:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://496.fwk1538849250:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Configuration Name: eclipse-formatter.epf
Starting format job ...
Done.
```

The preferences export is done once, then you can share `eclipse-formatter.epf` file.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I was really looking for a way to do this programmatically. But, assuming that the upstream XML file never changes, or that I don't have to deal with multiple XMLs, then I guess you're right that this can be done only once and the .prefs or .epf file can be shared. If the upstream XML spec changes, then I suppose I would use  howlger's suggestion in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, probably the title of your post should be changed :p . Here's and [IBM howto](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21273017) to export/import programmatically.