# Eclipse: Headless eclipse plugin to export preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have made a headless eclipse plugin using the following code:

```java
public class Application implements IApplication {

    @Override
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ok this is it!");
        IPreferencesService service = Platform.getPreferencesService();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/temp/ohno.epf"));
            service.exportPreferences(service.getRootNode(), fout, null);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

However why does

```java
service.exportPreferences(service.getRootNode(), fout, null);
```

write an empty file? The behaviour I was expecting was that it would be the same as exporting the Preferences through the File->Export [Preferences] menu. It must be that service.getRootNode is not returning what I would expect which is is the root of all preferences.

How can I get all preferences? Not only workspace preferences or default ones but the whole lot?

Comment: Interesting project. Seems you are missing the `scope` for the preferences as described [in the official docs](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fruntime_preferences.htm). Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592418/programmatically-export-eclipse-formatter-profile-xml-into-prefs/50594874#50594874) tried to do something similar. If you share your project I'm willing to cooperate.

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=6Ob1ANNVcXcC&pg=PA451&lpg=PA451&dq=IPreferencesService+service+%3D+Platform.getPreferencesService();&source=bl&ots=joDt7KWkuv&sig=xjvr1kj4HLGN_0qf5sjr_mU63lQ&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3obySh9LcAhXDDpAKHSBoAwgQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=IPreferencesService%20service%20%3D%20Platform.getPreferencesService()%3B&f=false) some more related info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this code Eclipse creates a new workspace for the run. All the preferences in this workspace are initially set to the default values. The `exportPreferences` method does not export preferences set to default values - so you don't get anything exported. You will need to set some preferences in this workspace to test this code.

Also note that the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Preferences` class has a helper method to do this export. You can replace you code with a call to:

```java
public static void exportPreferences(IPath path) throws CoreException
```

To get the 'configuration' scope only use:

```
IEclipsePreferences node = (IEclipsePreferences)service.getRootNode().node(ConfigurationScope.SCOPE);
```

Comment: I am looking to export the global eclipse settings rather than the workspace settings. Is that a scope thing as mentioned in the comments above?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'global'. Preferences scopes are 'configuration', 'instance', 'project' and 'default'. 'configuration' is closest  - see update to answer for getting this (but it will still be empty when you test).

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying. All eclipse preferences are based on workspaces. Preferences are stored no where else apart from the workspace store. I wasn't aware of that, I thought that there were "global" settings which were always present regardless of what workspace you use.

Comment: Not quite. 'configuration' scope settings are usually stored in the 'configuration' directory of the Eclipse installation so are more or less global. But when you test your code Eclipse creates a dummy configuration so that you don't damage the main Eclipse settings. Only a few preferences have configuration scope.